# Redis pub/sub replay last

Tags: redis

[Redis](http://redis.io/) supports pub/sub.
How can I have a client retrieve the last value and subscribe to changes, in such a way that I don't miss messages.
Here is the problem with get + subscribe:

1. I get the last value from Redis
2. subscribe to changes
3. before I store the last value from 1. I receive an update, and therefore update my cache with the update
4. I naively proceed to store the the value from 1. overwritting the value from 3

Comment: cant you just abort the point 4 (retrieve and stored via redis GET ) when an update is received from pub/sub channel ?

Comment: that makes sense. Now that you mentioned it, my question feels a bit stupid :-)